# MessageBox.Show not showing in form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm doing a tic tac toe game, and I want to show a message box when the user has won. But when I test it and click on button1, button2 and button3 nothing happens on the form or the console. I think I confused something with the == and = operators, but I'm not sure what exactly.

This is my current code:

```
bool buttonisclicked1 = false;
bool buttonisclicked2 = false;
bool buttonisclicked3 = false;

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button clickedButton1 = (Button)sender;
   clickedButton1.Text = "X";

   if (clickedButton1.Text == "X")
   {
      buttonisclicked1 = true;
   }
}

public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button clickedButton2 = (Button)sender;
   clickedButton2.Text = "X";

   if (clickedButton2.Text == "X")
   {
      buttonisclicked2 = true;
   }
}

public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button clickedButton3 = (Button)sender;
   clickedButton3.Text = "X";

   if (clickedButton3.Text == "X")
   {
      buttonisclicked3 = true;
   }
}

public void Win()
{
   if (buttonisclicked1 && buttonisclicked2 && buttonisclicked3 == true)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("You won");
      MessageBox.Show("You won!");
   }
}
```

Comment: Are your click handlers subscribed?  Debug the program.  When do you call the Win method?

Comment: Plus, why checking `if (clickedButton[N].Text == "X")` when you have set this condition in the previous line of code? Will the `X` ever lose?

Comment: As Jimi stated, if the whole output of a button is to change a `bool` value, and there's no way of anything else happening when the button is clicked (because you haven't written anything else to happen), you do not need the `if` statement within the `Click Event`.

Comment: Looks like you need to call `Win()` to evaluate your win condition every time you click on any button.

Comment: I use the if statement to check if the X was clicked three in a row, like in the game.  I don't know how to check it otherwise.

Comment: @Hashinu , you do not need to check if you make it set to that text *every time* it is clicked. Because it does nothing else, you would only need to set the `bool`

Comment: I have updated my answer with the code that would work just fine for what you are trying to do :) **NOTE:** Since you are using this in a `Winforms` , it's not necessary to have `Console.WriteLine()` , as that outlook will never be seen or used :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code it's not very elegant but with this should work:

```
 bool buttonisclicked1 = false;
bool buttonisclicked2 = false;
bool buttonisclicked3 = false;



public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton1 = (Button)sender;
    buttonisclicked1 = true;
    clickedButton1.Text = "X";

    Win();
}

public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton2 = (Button)sender;
    buttonisclicked2 = true;
    clickedButton2.Text = "X";
    Win();
}

public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton3 = (Button)sender;
     buttonisclicked3 = true;
    clickedButton3.Text = "X";
    Win();
}

        public void Win()
{
    if (buttonisclicked1 && buttonisclicked2 && buttonisclicked3 == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You won");
        MessageBox.Show("You won!");

    }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to have the `If` statement within the methods.

Comment: I really didn't notice that. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't ever call the `Win()` method. You declare it but do not utilize it.

```
    bool buttonisclicked1 = false;
    bool buttonisclicked2 = false;
    bool buttonisclicked3 = false;



    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button clickedButton1 = (Button)sender;
        clickedButton1.Text = "X";

        buttonisclicked1 = true;

        Win()
    }

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button clickedButton2 = (Button)sender;
        clickedButton2.Text = "X";

        buttonisclicked2 = true;

        Win()
    }

    public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button clickedButton3 = (Button)sender;
        clickedButton3.Text = "X";

        buttonisclicked3 = True;

        Win()
    }

    public void Win()
    {
        if (buttonisclicked1 && buttonisclicked2 && buttonisclicked3 == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You won");
            MessageBox.Show("You won!");

        }
    }
}
```

The reason I have put the the `Win()` in each `Click Event()` is that way it will check the conditions each time, despite the order of buttons clicked.

You do not need to have an `If` statement to check if the `.Text` property of the button has changed, as it is set to *always* change to `'X'`. If you had other conditions and code *within* the `Click Event`s that could either change the `.Text` property to something else, then it would make sense to have an `If` statement. Otherwise- it is not necessary.

And from what I can tell- you seem to be using `==` and `=` just fine within your `If` statements :)

Comment: This won't work either you are not modifying the properties of the class, you are creating a new variable within the method it won't compile.